# Check The Given Code Is Correct? Check by Regex(PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I'm providing a backlink selling service, but I have problem while checking the sold links on publisher web sites. For example I want to check

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" title="example">example</a>
```

I can check this but some users add `target="_blank"` some of them `target="_new"`... The code's structure is changing by the webmaster.

I want to check the codes with regex. The Regex should check `href=""`, `title=""` and between the a tags (`<a>here</a>`).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! A few clarifying questions: Do you mean that you want to ensure that your `<a>` tags only contain those two attributes? What exactly do you want to check between the opening and closing tag? And, incidentally, what's a backling selli(n)g service?

Comment: Yes absolutely you are right.. I want to check href and title.. And there shouldn't be rel="nofollow".. We are providing backlink to web sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made you this:

```
$str = "<a onclick=\"foo()\" href=\"http://www.example.com\" title=\"example\">example</a>" ;

function url_grab( $html )
{
    preg_match( "/<a\s+.*href=(\"|')([^\\1]+)(\\1).*>(.+)<\/a>/U" , $html , $m ) ;
    return array( $m[ 2 ] , $m[ 4 ] ) ;
}

// test it
var_dump( url_grab( $str ) ) ;
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "http://www.example.com"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "example"
}
```

Comment: hmm, i must have misread what you wrote - thought you only wanted href and what was between the tags

Comment: This is nearly what i want, just title is missing.. I don't understand regex, if you add title attribute it is completely ok. I mean i need, href, title and what was between the tags..

Answer (score 0):

Use [this parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead of regular expressions, which are cool but the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: You are right, this is a wrong tool for my need, but thanks for your interest.. I'm gonna write a tutorial about this ;)